# OpenSSH server: Other version running than installed

Tags: 18.04, openssh

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 server. I installed `openssh-server` and `openssh-client`. According to `apt`, the installed version of both packages is `7.6p1-4ubuntu0.1`, but the running version of the ssh-server (`sshd`) is `OpenSSH_6.7p2 Ubuntu-4p1`. The version of the client (`ssh`) is correct.

I already restarted the server several times, but the running version is still the same.

Recently I reinstalled OpenSSH, because my clients couldn't connect to the server with version 6.7. See: [SSH connection closed right after login](https://askubuntu.com/q/1091746/659750)

It worked for a while, but then it suddenly switched back to version 6.7. (the installed package is still 7.6)

Could anybody please help me with this? I don't understand how the running version can differ from the package version.

---

**Edit:**

This is the output of the command `dpkg -l | grep openssh` as requested in the comments:

```
ii  openssh-client                        1:7.6p1-4ubuntu0.2                         amd64        secure shell (SSH) client, for secure access to remote machines
ii  openssh-server                        1:7.6p1-4ubuntu0.2                         amd64        secure shell (SSH) server, for secure access from remote machines
ii  openssh-sftp-server                   1:7.6p1-4ubuntu0.2                         amd64        secure shell (SSH) sftp server module, for SFTP access from remote machines
```

It might also be worth noting that I get the following error in the syslog when trying to log in:

> sshd[15010]: segfault at ad6cd950 ip 00007f50883835a1 sp 00007ffcfb4f35f8 error 4 in libc-2.27.so[7f50881f5000+1e7000]

---

**Edit 2:**

After removing OpenSSH and reinstalling it again as [recommended in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1111152/659750), it worked for an hour. This did not happen after a reboot or update.
The actual `ssh.service` seems not to be running anymore. By running `ps -o unit -p <process id>`, I found out that the process has been started by `env.service`. I guess that is not correct, because right after the fresh installation, `sshd` has been started by `ssh.service`. But how can I change that behavior? I don't know, what `env.service` does.

---

**Edit 3:**

Something keeps replacing `/usr/sbin/sshd` with the old version within less than an hour after reinstalling `openssh-server`. I can see that the MD5 hash has been changed.

Comment: How did you determine that version `OpenSSH_6.7p2 Ubuntu-4p1` is running? What is the output of `dpkg -l | grep openssh`? Add both to your question by editing your question.

Comment: Package names (*and numbers*) are not the same as version numbers.

Comment: @Thomas I executed `sshd -V` (and `/usr/sbin/sshd -V` which resulted in the same output). Additionally, my client on OS X tells me that the server is using  `OpenSSH_6.7p2`. The output of your command is a table with openssh-client, -server and -sftp-server. The version is `1:7.6p1-4ubuntu0.1` for all of them.

Comment: @guiverc: not necessarily, but if you have such a big difference in versions, then something is wrong.

Comment: @FelixSFD: so `sshd -V` does result in `OpenSSH_6.7p2`? Did you somehow overwrite the binaries in `/usr/sbin/sshd` by copying things or similar?

Comment: @Thomas Actually, I get the "illegal option" error message, but this includes the version number. I never copied the binaries. A month ago I completely removed OpenSSH and [reinstalled it](https://askubuntu.com/a/1091937/659750) using [this tutorial](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-ssh-server-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux).

Comment: It seems that your server's system is doing something behind the curtain: automatically re-installs or at least reactivates the old version and starts using it. I run `openssh-server` in 18.04.1 LTS and it is has been started by `ssh.service`. I agree that it should be like that. Have you installed some service (server package), that might 'want' that old version of `sshd`?

Comment: @sudodus I have Webmin installed, but AFAIK this does not change any packages without asking for permission. Auto-updates are disabled. How can I find out, which program might be depending on this old version?

Comment: Sorry but I don't know how to identify the culprit. Let us hope that other people have good ideas:-) Maybe you can remember some other program package that you have installed. Is your server new or old? I mean, if your server is new, it might not cost too much time to re-install the whole server, but if it is old it is a different story.

Comment: Unfortunately, the server is not that new. It already runs a mail-server and other important stuff that took a while to set up :-/

Comment: Does anything other have such strange behavior? Does it possible to be hacked?

Comment: @pa4080 no. Everything else is working fine. At the time, when the file has been replaced, the service has been killed: `systemd[1]: ssh.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL` After that, I see the errors as described in the question

Answer (score 0):

1) Backup you config file

2) Remove via apt openssh-server

3) Reboot

4) Run apt update

5) Run apt-get autoremove

6) Reinstall openssh-server. (for Ubuntu 18.04 the versiòn is 1:7.6)

Comment: I already reinstalled `openssh-server` several times, but after some days, it keeps switching back to the old version